# hp exstream table (section) has rows but received error saying no rows

Tags: hp-exstream

On a client page I have multiple tables/sections. I am trying to add a new table/section in between 1st and 2nd table/section. When I added the table and tried to execute the pub locally, the table does not show up in the output PDF and I can see a message in messages.dat -
"EX004061I (1) The table named Client Information Section (number 1 on the flow list) on page client page was deleted because it had no rows."
In contrast to the error message I do have 17 rows in the table. Do anyone know how to get my new table displayed in output pdf?

Comment: Are you sure that error is for the correct customer?

Comment: There are quite a lot of options where you could set something wrong or not at all so its impossible to tell you what is wrong without seeing your design and implementation. I would suggest to create driver file with only one customer and put some hardcoded values into your new table. Re run and then go from there.